# Convert EXE to a bootable ISO image

Tags: iso-image, bootable-media

I have an exe file which i want to convert into ISO as a bootable image.. (like an OS which may run on a VM)

Is this possible by any means?

btw, i have:
Windows 7 SP1
in x86 laptop

Comment: No, an exe is not an operating system.  Lets start with a simple question like *what is supposed to run the boot loader*?  What is supposed to run the instructions or provide memory management or process management for the exe?  Embedded devices run "applications" against what is called "bare metal" and they work this way.  A windows application does not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not easily. Your .exe likely refers to DLLs and file systems provided by Windows. You would need to provide those yourself - either by building a CD that loaded Windows and then your code, or by compiling equivalent functions into your code. Developers who need to do this often compile on Linux because they can use it for free on their CD.

For personal use you *might* be able to create a system repair disk and change what it runs at boot. That's not public information, though, so you'd have to reverse engineer it... or find someone who has.